# How to display a listing template of a certain taxonomy?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, templates

I'm trying to figure out how to display a list of specific taxonomy (`categorycourses`).

In `functions.php` for the theme I have:

```
//Register custom taxonomy for courses-categories
$course_cat_args = array(
  'hierarchical' => true,
  'labels' => $course_cat_labels, //Other labels set before
  'show_ui' => true,
  'show_admin_column' => true,
  'query_var' => true,
  'rewrite' => array( 'hierarchical' => true )
);

register_taxonomy( 'categorycourses', array('course'), $course_cat_args );
```

The actual taxonomy is working fine in admin.

Now I'm trying to create a template for `categorycourses` at frontend that lists all coursecategories.

I've looked at the [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display) and I thought I should create a file with the taxonomy name `categorycourses.php`

So I created a file called `categorycourses.php` in the themes folder. I also tried creating `categorycourses-categorycourse.php`, `archive-categorycourses.php` but I just keep getting a 404 error.

Please bare with me. I understand lot of backend-stuff in WP, but I'm just learning how to create templates at frontend.

I'm able to create archive-pages for certain post typs, so rewrites rules and so on are working on my local server.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
1. I've tried to create a file name `taxonomy-categorycourses.php` and with same result (404 error) I've flushed permalink-settings in admin by resaving them

I've also tried:

```
$course_cat_args = array(
  'hierarchical' => true,
  'labels' => $course_cat_labels,
  'show_ui' => true,
  'show_admin_column' => true,
  'query_var' => true,
  'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'soup')
);

register_taxonomy( 'categorycourses', array('course'), $course_cat_args );
```

I try to access the template with `http://server/soup` but still get the error. (after resaving permalink-settings in admin)

**UPDATE2:**
**I think I've figured it out:**
There don't seem to be any template for "root-taxonomy". You have to choose a specific coursecategory to act as a root.

In my case I've created this file:

```
taxonomy-categorycourses-semester2014.php
```

When I then access `http://server/soup/semester2014` the expected template (t`axonomy-categorycourses-semester2014.php`) is shown.

But there seems no way to actually create a "root template for a taxonomy" like `http://server/soup/` . Even if I create a template called `taxonomy-categorycourses.php` it does not work.

**Is this correct?**

Comment: So much for your SE handle....

Comment: haha :-) But still. It didn't say I'm best at WP ;-)

Comment: Have a look also at [this tutorial](https://mondaybynoon.com/revisiting-custom-post-types-taxonomies-permalinks-slugs/).

Comment: Yes, but if you read_ "When taxonomy-brands.php is saved, we can now visit http://example.com/cameras/brands/canon/ to view our Custom Taxonomy archive:". It does not say that you can access http://example.com/cameras/brands directly. I've tried this as well, just by adding has_archive to true in the cpt, but still it does not work as I wanted to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want to do is impossible without a `page.php` type of template. There is no [template hierarchy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) that support what you want to achieve. It works exactly the same with categories. `taxonomy-categorycourses.php` will not display a list of `categorycourses`, so would `category-categorycourses.php` if `categorycourses` was a normal category. If you click on `categorycourses`, you will be taken to a page that will display posts from that taxonomy or category.

If you need to show a list of terms or categories under a taxonomy, you will need to create a custom `page.php` template and use [`get_the_terms()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms) to get a list of all the terms/categories attached to a taxonomy. [`wp_list_categories( $args )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_categories) will output the list, so you can modify this to display what you need. You can make a copy of your themes' `page.php` template and call it something like `page-tax.php` You need to change the loop in this template. Here is an example for the twentyfourteen theme.

```
 <?php
/**
 * Template Name: Page Tax
 */
get_header(); ?>

<div id="main-content" class="main-content">

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

        <?php //list terms in a given taxonomy using wp_list_categories (also useful as a widget if using a PHP Code plugin)

            $taxonomy     = 'brands';
            $orderby      = 'name'; 
            $show_count   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
            $pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
            $hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
            $title        = '';

            $args = array(
              'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
              'orderby'      => $orderby,
              'show_count'   => $show_count,
              'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
              'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
              'title_li'     => $title
            );

        ?>

        <ul>
            <?php wp_list_categories( $args ); ?>
        </ul>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
    <?php get_sidebar( 'content' ); ?>
</div><!-- #main-content -->

<?php
get_footer();
```

Just remember to change `$taxonomy = 'brands';` to your taxonomy name. You can now create a new page in the "Add New Page" screen, set your page slug to the taxonomy name , and select this template. You can now enter `http://server/categorycourses/` and you will be directed to this page you created.

**Original Answer**
Your answer is right in the link you provided. The codex states it perfectly, you just need to implement it correctly. Your template should be called `taxonomy-categorycourses.php`. Please refer to the link you provided

**UPDATE1**
Hit me like a ton of bricks, had the same problem a while ago with a CPT, and I missed that when I looked at your code. For your custom template to work, you need to add `'has_archive' => true,` to your arguments when registering your **custom post type**. For your info, go and check [registering taxonomies](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) and [registering custom post types](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)

Comment: Hm. I can't get this to work either (even it seems most logical). I still don't understand. Should I access the page with http://domain/taxonomy-categorycourses ? (I tried that and tried http://domain/categorycourses) but I still have the same issue.

Comment: Ok, thanks very much for the clarification and your effort trying to make sense of my question :-)

Comment: It's my pleasure, just glad your problem is sorted