# Template to list categories in custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I refer to this post where I have just taken my code from: [How to display a listing template of a certain taxonomy?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/140470/how-to-display-a-listing-template-of-a-certain-taxonomy)

I am trying to create a page template that will list all categories in "servicecats" taxonomy which is linked to the custom post-type "Services".

In the page template I have used the code taken from the link above:

```
<?php

        $taxonomy     = 'servicecats';
        $orderby      = 'name'; 
        $show_count   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
        $pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
        $hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
        $title        = '';

        $args = array(
          'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
          'orderby'      => $orderby,
          'show_count'   => $show_count,
          'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
          'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
          'title_li'     => $title
        );

    ?>
<?php wp_list_categories( $args ); ?>
```

When I view the page, it just says "No categories" although I do have 4 set up, the taxonomy and post-type are both hierarchical.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to sort this using:

```
<?php $category_ids = get_all_category_ids(); ?>
      <?php
      $args = array(
         'orderby' => 'slug',
         'parent' => 0,
        'taxonomy' => 'servicecats'
      );
      $categories = get_categories( $args );
      foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
         echo '<li><img src=""/><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" rel="bookmark">' . $category->name . '' . '' . $category->description . '</a></li>';
      }
     ?>
```

Would still like to know how to also show the empty categories though if anyone could offer advice on this?

Comment: You should accept your own answer. Please help keeping the site clean of unnecessary open questions :-)

Comment: Sorry Pieter, I did try to when I posted but told me I could only accept my own answer after x days and then forgot to come back.

Comment: Why you create that $category_ids but never use it?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `'hide_empty'` and set it to `false` as it's `true` per *default*.

```
wp_list_categories( array(
    'hide_empty' => false,
) );
```

Answer (score 1):

The code in question works and I can only think of two reasons why it fails

- Wrong taxonomy name supplied
- The terms assigned to taxonomy is empty

I would suggest that you get [`wp_list_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) working as it is faster and less resource intensive than [`get_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories)

To get empty terms, simply add the `hide_empty` parameter to your arguments and set it to `0`